# sum up data in a matrix using a for loop

Tags: r

I have the following data matrix called *joint*. The values (o,1) are outcomes of 3 Bernouille trials. The probabilty of each trial is stored in the column "prob".

```
    > joint
     z1 z2 z3    prob
[1,]  0  0  0 0.09375
[2,]  1  0  0 0.03125
[3,]  0  1  0 0.09375
[4,]  0  0  1 0.28125
[5,]  1  1  0 0.03125
[6,]  0  1  1 0.28125
[7,]  1  0  1 0.09375
[8,]  1  1  1 0.09375
```

What I need is to compute the probability densities (PDF) for each value (this is: 0, 1, 2 and 3) and store them in the column pdf in the following matrix called *sumpdf*:

```
    > sumpdf
     sum pdf cdf
[1,]   0   0   0
[2,]   1   0   0
[3,]   2   0   0
[4,]   3   0   0
```

Actually I could just sum up the probabilities for each value, but I am looking for an elegant way to solve the problem (e.g. using an for- or apply-function) - up to now without success ;-(

Comment: What are the pdf you want to compute? The pdfs of the variables whose realizations are in each column of your matrix?

Comment: i would like to compute the PDF of Z = z1, z2, z3 for each value in its support, yeah. So basically for the values 0, 1, 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
d$sum <- d$z1 + d$z2 + d$z3
sumpdf <- aggregate(d$prob, by = list(sum = d$sum), FUN = sum)
names(sumpdf)[2] <- "pdf"
sumpdf$cdf <- cumsum(sumpdf$pdf)
sumpdf
#  sum     pdf     cdf
#1   0 0.09375 0.09375
#2   1 0.40625 0.50000
#3   2 0.40625 0.90625
#4   3 0.09375 1.00000
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only, the probability is not 0.5, but differs: z1 = 0.25, z2 = 0.5, z3 = 0.75. This is why the probability of for example the realizations 001 and 010 differ.

Comment: I see so when you say pdf and cdf you are referring to the distribution of their sum. I have updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The aggregate-function is a nice solution!